# How to handle the alert of FIDO authentication in selenium?

Tags: selenium, fido

As title, there would be a alert "verify your identity with webauthn.io" poped when I regisetered a user through FIDO. The alert might have some options. My target is to write a script that can automatically sign in a website by selenium, but I have no idea how to handle this alert in selenium.

Is there any way to handle this alert?

[the alert be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKhKn.png)

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes you could use a virtual authenticator. Chromium based browsers have the option to emulate WebAuthn/FIDO2 authenticators - https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/webauthn/

I've found when the virtual authenticator is enabled, it'll "bypass" the menu in your image above. The WebAuthn ceremony is still completed, the menu just immediately utilizes the virtual authenticator when enabled. The same will be true for authentication

Some considerations

- This is not an option in all browsers (notably Firefox and Safari)
- For application testing I highly recommend that you still perform a round of manual testing utilizing a real authenticator (YubiKey, Face ID, Windows Hello, etc..)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your knowledge. But I still have a question. 
In my case, I'm trying to login to my website with a real authenticator and selenium headless. I want to verify an user only through terminal, that is, the graphic part of browser isn't rendered.  I expect the selenium script can replace all human actions on the browser, keep exec until ```navigator.credential.create``` is called. 
How should I write a selenium script to meet the considerations above?

Comment: Selenium will be outside the scope of my knowledge - I'd attempt to see if the tool can press those browser prompts

But with an authenticator you still have to consider:
* Does this authenticator need to be physically activated for user presence
* How do you handle being prompted for the user verification PIN, as you wouldn't want to hardcode this into a script

Both will require a manual step by the user that can't be automated, especially if you are using an authenticator with the features, and the login service requires both the manual steps